# How to iterate over a tf.dataset, without deprecated functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 1.14 and have a problem with dataset.

my code:

```
my_data = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7]
]

slices = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(my_data) # get dataset
it = slices.make_one_shot_iterator() # get iterator from dataset (deprecated)
next_item = it.get_next()
```

It says make_one_shot_iterator is deprecated..

So i tried following codes

```
my_data = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7]
]

slices = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(my_data) # get dataset
for q in slices:
    print(sess.run(q))
```

Immediately i got NotFoundError exception.

My question: What is the proper way to iterate over a dataset?

Comment: How about `tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator` and `tf.compat.v1.data.make_initializable_iterator`??

Comment: Another example of the shoddy documentation in tensorflow. Literally the thing they tell you to try throws an exception.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725172/iterating-over-a-dataset-tf-2-0-with-for-loop#comment103459584_58158402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
my_data = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7]
]
n = len(my_data)
slices = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(my_data) # get dataset
iterator = slices.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while n>0:
        print(sess.run(iterator.get_next()))
        n-=1
```

If above still showing `deprecation` message, then try below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

my_data = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7]
]
slices = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(my_data) # get dataset
for i in slices:
    print(i.numpy())
```

output:

```
[0 1]
[2 3]
[4 5]
[6 7]
```

Comment: `make_initializable_iterator` is deprecated

Comment: @user3681105, I added a new way of iterating over a dataset. Check my code above. But that will only work if eager execution is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#as_numpy_iterator) you can do a simple loop with:

```
for element in my_dataset: 
   print(element)
```

As you can see in the image, this returns a `tf.Tensor`. If you want a simple tuple you can use:

```
for element in my_dataset.as_numpy_iterator(): 
   print(element)
```

If each entry of your dataset has more than one element you can index the contents of the tuple with `[]` like normally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
my_data = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7]
]

slices = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(my_data) # get dataset
q = slices.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(len(my_data)):
        print('-----')
        print(sess.run(q))
```

The code above produces
[image]